# Life cycle of views created by getView method of BaseAdapter subclass

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a problem related with life cycle of views created by custom adapter for common `ListView`. I created  a custom view as follows:

```
    public class NSViewZoneLarge extends RelativeLayout
    {
        private long mZoneId;
        private ToggleButton mOnOffButton;

        public NSViewZoneLarge(Context context, boolean showSwitch, long zoneId)
        {
            super(context);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_zone_large, this);
            mOnOffButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonOnOff);

            ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewZoneType);
            imgView.setFocusable(false);

            if (showSwitch)
            {
                mOnOffButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                mOnOffButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mOnOffButton.setEnabled(false);
                mOnOffButton.setFocusable(false);
                mOnOffButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            }

            mZoneId = zoneId;
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public NSViewZoneLarge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void setZoneName(String zoneName)
        {
            TextView tVZoneName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewZoneName);
            tVZoneName.setText(zoneName);
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public String getZoneName()
        {
            TextView tVZoneName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewZoneName);
            return tVZoneName.getText().toString();
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void setOnOffButton(boolean isOn)
        {
            ToggleButton onOffButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonOnOff);
            onOffButton.setChecked(isOn);
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public boolean isOnOffButtonChecked()
        {
            ToggleButton onOffButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonOnOff);
            return onOffButton.isChecked();
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public long getZoneId()
        {
            return mZoneId;
        }
}
```

Then I instantiate this view in `getView()` method of my `BaseAdapter` subclass:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    NSDestinationContent destinationContent = mDestinationContents.get(position);
    NSViewZoneLarge viewZone = new NSViewZoneLarge(mContext, mShowSwitches, destinationContent.mDestinationContentId);

    viewZone.setZoneName(destinationContent.mName);

    if (mShowSwitches)
        viewZone.setOnOffButton(mOnOffStates.get(position));

    if (destinationContent.mDestinationTypeId.equals(DestinationTypeId.SPEAKERS_GROUP))
    {
        NSSpeakerGroup speakerGroup = (NSSpeakerGroup) destinationContent;
        viewZone.setZoneType(speakerGroup.mZoneTypeId);
    }

    return viewZone;
}
```

Finally, I set `OnItemLongClickListener` for the `listView`:

```
    mZonesListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            NSViewZoneLarge viewZoneLarge = (NSViewZoneLarge)view;
            long destinationId = viewZoneLarge.getZoneId();
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText(NSConstants.DRAG_KEY_ZONE_ID, String.valueOf(destinationId));

            view.startDrag(data, new DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);

            Intent intent = new TrashBinIntent(true);
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ApplicationNetSpeaker.getInstance());
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that method `getZoneId()` returns always null although I set this value through the `NSViewZoneLarge` constructor in `getView()` method correctly.

I know why it returns null; it is because `OnItemLongClickListener` gives me an instance of `NSViewZoneLarge` which is not the one created by `getView()` method. Somewhere, somehow the `NSViewZoneLarge` instance is created with the second – default constructor only.

I also tried to use `setTag()` method to associate data with the view, but the `getTag()` method always returns null – again, the original instance is lost somewhere, probably released by GC, and I get a new instance with no tag set instead.

Can somebody explain me why this occurs and how can I associate any kind of data with a particular view of `ListView` item?